# cudaGetDeviceCount returns 0 on parallel execution on > 2 CPUs

Tags: cuda, openmpi

I am having some issues with `cudaGetDeviceCount` returning zero if used in `mpirun` with `-np` greater than `2`.  The portion of code from a much larger program is:

```
bool cpuInterfaces::checkGPUCount(int gpusPerMachine){

    int GPU_N;
    cudaGetDeviceCount(&GPU_N);

    //if the gpu count on this node does not equal what was given in fvSolution, return false
    return ((gpusPerMachine>GPU_N || gpusPerMachine < 1)? false : true);

}
```

The larger portion of code is located at [cufflink-source file](https://code.google.com/p/cufflink-library/source/browse/trunk/lduMatrix/solvers/CFL_Headers/cpuInterfaces.C).  If a run is executed using `mpirun -np 2 somethingsomething` then everything runs fine and `cudaGetDeviceCount` returns `4`, where as if `mpirun -np 4 somethingsomething` will result in `cudaGetDeviceCount` returning zero.  Are there special cases of using `cudaGetDeviceCount` in MPI that I'm not aware of?  Any help or suggestions would be helpful.

Comment: `cudaGetDeviceCount()` returns an error code, which should be examined first.

Comment: Besides, it is returning zero in all ranks or only in some of them?

Comment: Its returning zero in all the ranks.  I will look into the error code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to those that provided some answers.  This turned out to be an issue with a driver.  After waiting for a bit, a driver update resolved this question.

Comment: Which driver update? Which hardware are you using?